# How to clone a single directory of an entire Git repository?

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

Anyone knows how to clone a single directory from a git repository by using a command line?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are talking about sparse checkout, see more on this link: http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/